# Passing data from DB to update form using CI CRUD

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to write a compact update controller for CRUD activity. Here is the basic code:

Controller:

```
function update($id)
    {           
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','required');            
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('age','Age','required|is_numeric');           
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('country','Country','');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error">', '</span>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            //Failed validation or first run
            $data = $this->my_model->get_record($id);

            $this->load->view('myform_view', $data);

        } else {

            //Validation success, update DB

        }
    }
```

View:

```
<?php  

$attributes = array('class' => '', 'id' => '');
echo form_open('my_form', $attributes); ?>

<p>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
        <br /><input id="name" type="text" name="name"  value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>"  />
</p>

<p>
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <?php echo form_error('age'); ?>
        <br /><input id="age" type="text" name="age"  value="<?php echo set_value('age'); ?>"  />
</p>

<p>
        <label for="country">Country</label>
        <?php echo form_error('country'); ?>
        <br /><input id="country" type="text" name="country"  value="<?php echo set_value('country'); ?>"  />
</p>


<p>
        <?php echo form_submit( 'submit', 'Submit'); ?>
</p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

This is the basic structure, however the first time the form is run there is no validated data. Therefore I have to grab this from the DB. Whats the best way to pass this to the view on the first run? And then once the form has been submitted, if validation fails then I want the failed data to show not to reload from the DB again. Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have another method for the viewing aspect. Then submit your form against the "update" method. In there, you define the the form_validation as you have now.

I asked a similar question. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034002/codeigniter-form-validation-when-updating-records)

Comment: Theres no way to compact it all into one controller? Also how do I populate the view file. At the moment I use set_value().

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think you're asking the same thing I had asked a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

grab the data in update controller first for edit such as

```
$query = $this->db->where('id',$id)->get('table_name');
$data['edit'] = $query->result_array();
```

and then check it in view file

```
  value="<?php if(isset($edit[0]['age'])){echo $edit[0]['age'];}else{echo set_value('age');}?>"
```